# SendGrid works from console app but not ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I have a snippet of `SendGrid` code that works perfectly from inside a `.NET Framework 4.7.2` console app, but fails inside a `.NET Framework 4.7.2` ASP.NET page. This is unrelated (I think) to `async/await` as described in these 2 similar SO posts:

[SendGrid hanging only in web app (not in console app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005712/sendgrid-hanging-only-in-web-app-not-in-console-app)

[await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock)

The reason that async/await is not involved (it seems) is because (due to problems I've had with SendGrid .NET SDK) I bypassed the SendGrid SDK entirely and went with raw JSON posts--without using async/await anywhere.

The code below works great in a console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string result = sendEmail();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string sendEmail()
    {
        string apiKey = "SG.hlU...swAWk";
        string apiUrl = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send";

        string emailJson = @"
        {
           ""personalizations"":[
              {
                 ""to"":[
                    {
                       ""email"":""he...er@gmail.com"",
                    }
                 ],
                 ""subject"":""Hello from SendGrid""
              }
           ],
           ""from"":{
              ""email"":""na....p.com"",
              ""name"":""In... Sender""
           },
           ""content"":[
              {
                 ""type"":""text/html"",
                 ""value"":""<p>This is an HTML email.</p>""
              }
           ]
        }";

        var headers = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}" },
            { "Content-Type", "application/json" }
        };

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            // Set headers
            client.Headers.Add(headers);

            try
            {
                string response = client.UploadString(apiUrl, "POST", emailJson);
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                return "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But when I copy the `sendEmail()` method over into an ASP.NET web page and run it, I always get these errors:

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
> existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host

*Why??*

[Note: If you copy/paste my code into a console app and inject a valid SendGrid API key, and fix the email addresses, you'll see it works. But try the same thing in an ASP.NET page and it breaks.]